# How to change the color of the Title bar when running a GUI program?

Tags: java, titlebar

I want to change the color of the title bar and also the Java icon on the upper left of the frame, so I can make my program (GUI) look better. Is there a simple way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how useful this observation is, but under the *X Window System* (e.g. on *Linux*), the titlebar and the icons in it aren't usually under the control of the application, they're “decorations” under the control of the window manager (WM). I'm not sure exactly how this might impact a Java program — they *might* be able to use undecorated windows and add their own equivalent — but it's equally possible that what you want to do simply isn't possible (without an inordinate amount of effort) on any platform.